# How do I add "sheetId": XXXXXX to my Google Sheets v4 function batchupdate?

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I'm almost finished with my application where I'm able to do a simple delete off of Google Spraedsheet data. However, I have not been able to find a method where I could add the sheetId and its respective GID # to the request arraylist.

```
private void deleteRow()
{
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

    DeleteDimensionRequest deleteDimensionRequest = new DeleteDimensionRequest();

    DimensionRange dimensionRange = new DimensionRange();
    dimensionRange.getDimension();
    dimensionRange.setStartIndex(13);
    dimensionRange.setEndIndex(14);

    deleteDimensionRequest.setRange(dimensionRange);
    Sheets.Spreadsheets spreadsheets = null;

    requests.add(new Request()
            //There should be a function call or some sort for me to
            //add a sheetid... if I do the updatesheets property here
            //I get an error message saying that there's already a kind
            //and I cannot set the id
            .setDeleteDimension(deleteDimensionRequest)
    );

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
            .setRequests(requests);

    try
    {
        mService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate("SPREADSHEETID GOES HERE", batchUpdateRequest).execute();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the strategy to add the sheet values into the request arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

The function calls were actually available after creating a new constructor for *DimensionRange*.

Simply do:

```
    dimensionRange.setDimension("ROWS");
    dimensionRange.setSheetId(XXXXX);
```

to finish the JSON post request to Sheets API...